# CNTK with python - activation for each layer

Tags: python, conv-neural-network, cntk

I am using the python API of CNTK to train some CNN that I save using the save_model function.

Now I want to run some analysis on my network afterwards. Specifically I want to take a look at the activations of each layer. Obviously I can run my network on some data called img like this:

```
model.eval(img)
```

But that will only give me the output of the **last** Layer in my Network. Is there some easy way to also get the output from the previous layers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, there is even an example provided for that task: https://github.com/Microsoft/CNTK/tree/master/Examples/Image/FeatureExtraction

Let me give you a short overview about the essential steps:

Important is the name of your node, of which you want to get the output.

```
# get the node in the graph of which you desire the output
node_in_graph = loaded_model.find_by_name(node_name)
output_nodes  = combine([node_in_graph.owner])

# evaluate the node e.g. using a minibatch_source
mb = minibatch_source.next_minibatch(1)
output = output_nodes.eval(mb[features_si])

# access the values as a one dimensional vector
out_values = output[0].flatten()
desired_output = out_values[np.newaxis]
```

Basically you just do the same like you do anyways with the difference that you retrieve an intermediate node.